# Async Sockets and cleaning up resources

Tags: c#, sockets

If I have a callback from a

```
listener.BeginAcceptSocket(cbConnect, listener);
```

and my callback method:

```
private void cbConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;
    MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
    myObj.socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    myObj.socket = listener.EndAcceptSocket(ar);
    listener.BeginAcceptSocket(cbConnect, listener);//start listening again
    myObj.socket.BeginReceive(myObj.buffer, 0, myObj.buffer.Length, 0, cbReceive, myObj);
}
```

Here is MyObj class:

```
Public class MyObj
{
    public Socket socket;
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[1080];
}
```

My question is if the client on the other end of the connection never sends any data what will happen to myObj? 
How would I close the socket and mop up resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remote connection drops, the socket should cleanup on it's own via the Garbage Collector.

Comment: If the connection is not dropped but no data is sent will the GC clean up myObj?

Comment: No. If you want to set some idle timeout, you will need to setup a timer which closes the socket. You might want to establish a protocol so you can send an idle timeout notification to the other end so it knows why the connection dropped. Once you close the socket, the async receive will stop and the reference to myObj will fall out and the GC will collect it all on the next pass (assuming nothing else holds a reference).

Comment: You might also consider using UDP as it wont maintain connections and resources.